# Measuring Impact Force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, projectile, education, home-experiment

My daughter is doing a project for school measuring the difference in impact force in softball with a mask vs without a mask. The systems I've looking into purchasing cost $1000. Please advise on how we might be able to complete this project without breaking the bank.

Comment: It's hard to comment without knowing what sort of measurements you are trying to make. Have you a link to the $1000 system you mentioned so we can see what it does?

Comment: It's a force sensor from Tekscan. The sensor is $52 for a pack of 4 but the system to read the sensor is $899+. We're basically trying to measure the impact to the head with a mask and without the mask.

Comment: The key point is that when the ball bumps your face without the mask it generates high pressure on the impact point. While if you wear the mask the force is spread on the mask and this reduces the pressure and so also the damage on your face.